# How to make a device available for a Bluetooth connection in Windows

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing an application that involves creating a Bluetooth connection between an Android device and a Windows 10/11 device. Getting the Android section working was pretty straight forward thanks to the detailed documentation, but not so much on desktop.

I want to get the local Bluetooth MAC address of my Windows device and then make it available from connection by the Android device which will use that MAC address to connect directly without needing to go through the discovery process.

I would like to use Java for the Windows application if possible. All I can find is from Oracle explaining it using the core Bluetooth API, but this seems to be removed from current versions of Java as the javax.bluetooth package isn't found. I'm using OpenJDK 17.0.2. Any similar stackoverflow questions I could find are extremely old and mention using this javax.bluetooth package which no longer exists.

Can anyone explain how we work with Bluetooth in Java in 2022? Are there any other languages that it is much easier to work with in you would reccommend over Java?

Comment: Do you want to connect using Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy for your connection?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Bluetooth Classic; however, if know of a BLE option then I can switch the Android client to work with that.